# Function Overloading, Could Not Deduce Template Argument

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, overloading

I'm trying to overload a Sum function which accepts a [list or vector] start and end iterator as arguments. This compiler error is really confusing me. Relevant code is as follows:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
const double Sum(const typename T1::const_iterator& start_iter, const typename T2::const_iterator& end_iter)
{// overloaded function that calculates sum between two iterators
    typename T1::const_iterator iterator_begin = start_iter;
    typename T2::const_iterator iterator_end = end_iter;

    double my_sum = 0;

    for (iterator_begin; iterator_begin != iterator_end; iterator_begin++)
        my_sum += *iterator_begin;

    return my_sum;      
}

int main()
{

list<double> test_list(10,5.1);
cout << Sum(test_list.begin(), test_list.end()); // compiler errors here

}
```

I get the following compiler errors:

> iterators.cpp(72): error C2783: 'const double Sum(const
>   T1::const_iterator &,const T2::const_iterator &)' : could not deduce
>   template argument for 'T1'
>
> iterators.cpp(72): error C2783: 'const double Sum(const
>   T1::const_iterator &,const T2::const_iterator &)' : could not deduce
>   template argument for 'T2'
>
> iterators.cpp(72): error C2780: 'const double Sum(const
>   std::map &)' : expects 1 arguments - 2 provided
>
> iterators.cpp(72): error C2780: 'const double Sum(const T &)' :
>   expects 1 arguments - 2 provided

How is the compiler not recognizing I'm trying to call the Sum function with two inputs? I'm calling the function incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need to tell it that iterators have to be members of some types `T1` and `T2`, just template it on iterator type itself:

```
template <typename Iter>
const double Sum(Iter iterator_begin, Iter iterator_end)
{
    double my_sum = 0;
    for (; iterator_begin != iterator_end; ++iterator_end)
        my_sum += *iterator_begin;
    return my_sum;      
}

int main()
{
    std::list<double> test_list;
    std::cout << Sum(test_list.begin(), test_list.end());
    return 0;
}
```

also there is a standard [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) that does this:

```
int main()
{
    std::list<double> test_list;
    std::cout << std::accumulate(test_list.begin(), test_list.end(), 0.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How could I keep them const though?

Comment: @Clark You can't.  You probably don't want to; the distinction between `iterator` and `const_iterator` is not relevant in a lot of cases (e.g. input iterators).  If you document the template as accepting input iterators (`template <typename InputIterator>`, rather than just `Iter`), then it is clear that the function doesn't mutate the sequence.  Otherwise, you document that it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

First, I don't think you want to do this.  Not all sequences have an
underlying container.  (Think of `istream_iterator`s, for example.)  And
more importantly, you're distinctly allowing (and even encouraging)
begin and end iterators from different containers; there is *no* case
where you could legally use this function where `T1` and `T2` have
different types.  The template should have a single parameter, which
should be an iterator; and by convention, the constraints on the
iterator should be expressed in the name of the parameter, e.g.
`InputIterator` (the case here), `ForwardIterator`, etc.

As to why your code doesn't compile:

> In most cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used
>   to compose P participate in template argument deduction. That is, they
>   may be used to determine the value of a template argument, and the
>   value so determined must be consistent with the values determined
>   elsewhere. In certain contexts, however, the value does not
>   participate in type deduction, but instead uses the values of template
>   arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified.
>   If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is
>   not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> — The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a
>   qualified-id.
>
> [...]

(From §14.8.2.5/4,5.)

Answer (score 2):

Call method like this..

```
Sum<list<double>,list<double> >(test_list.begin(), test_list.begin());
```